# How to Split JavaScript Array Elements if an Object property has certain delimitter

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, split

I have an array of objects and some of the objects have a property that has commas in it. What I want to do is if that object has a property that has commas in it, I want to split that into a new object and recursively copy all the other properties into a new array element.

Example:
I need to convert this array of objects:

```
[ { 
    prop1: ' text1 , text2 , text3 ',
    prop2: 'stuff1',
    prop3: 'stuff1',
    prop4: 'stuff1',
    prop5: 'https://www.stuff1.com' },

  { 
    prop1: ' text1 , text2 , text3 ',
    prop2: 'stuff2',
    prop3: 'stuff2',
    prop4: 'stuff2',
    prop5: 'https://www.awefewfew.com' },

 ]
```

to this:

```
[ { 
    prop1: 'text1',
    prop2: 'stuff1',
    prop3: 'stuff1',
    prop4: 'stuff1',
    prop5: 'https://www.stuff1.com' },

    { 
    prop1: 'text2',
    prop2: 'stuff1',
    prop3: 'stuff1',
    prop4: 'stuff1',
    prop5: 'https://www.stuff1.com' },

    { 
    prop1: 'text3 ',
    prop2: 'stuff1',
    prop3: 'stuff1',
    prop4: 'stuff1',
    prop5: 'https://www.stuff1.com' },   

  { 
    prop1: 'text1',
    prop2: 'stuff2',
    prop3: 'stuff2',
    prop4: 'stuff2',
    prop5: 'https://www.awefewfew.com' },

      { 
    prop1: 'text2',
    prop2: 'stuff2',
    prop3: 'stuff2',
    prop4: 'stuff2',
    prop5: 'https://www.awefewfew.com' },

      { 
    prop1: 'text3',
    prop2: 'stuff2',
    prop3: 'stuff2',
    prop4: 'stuff2',
    prop5: 'https://www.awefewfew.com' },  
 ]
```

By splitting at prop1, then recursively copying all the other properties into the new array element.

edit:
I was able to figure it out actually in google sheets but couldn't quite port this over to vanilla JS:

```
function splitColumnAndRepeatRows(anArray, splitColumnIndex) {
  var output = [];
  for (i in anArray){ 
    var splitArray = anArray[i][splitColumnIndex].split(","); 
    for (j in splitArray){ 
      var row = anArray[i].slice(0); 
      row[splitColumnIndex] = alltrim(splitArray[j]); 
      output.push(row); 
    }
  }
  return output;
}

function alltrim(str) {
  return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? 
StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to 
[try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). 
Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a 
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
For further information, please see 
[how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
and take the 
[tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: @Maxinef23 I added answer, hope it will work as per your expectation. Thanks

Comment: @JaromandaX fair point. Added what I had come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the succinctness of `array.concat` combined with `reduce()` and `map()` for this, but obviously there's a lot of ways to do it. It's not clear that your `prop1` strings will always have spaces, so this uses a small regex to get rid of the them.

```js
let arr = [ { prop1: ' text1 , text2 , text3 ',prop2: 'stuff1',prop3: 'stuff1',prop4: 'stuff1',prop5: 'https://www.stuff1.com' },{ prop1: ' text1 , text2 , text3 ',prop2: 'stuff2',prop3: 'stuff2',prop4: 'stuff2',prop5: 'https://www.awefewfew.com' },]

let final = arr.reduce((a, {prop1, ...obj}) => a.concat(
        prop1.trim()
        .split(/\s*,\s*/)
        .map(prop => ({prop1: prop, ...obj}))
    ), [])

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.reduce` to iterate over the input, split the `prop1` by `,`, then add each to the output array:

```js
const input=[{prop1:' text1 , text2 , text3 ',prop2:'stuff1',prop3:'stuff1',prop4:'stuff1',prop5:'https://www.stuff1.com'},{prop1:' text1 , text2 , text3 ',prop2:'stuff2',prop3:'stuff2',prop4:'stuff2',prop5:'https://www.awefewfew.com'},]
const ouput = input.reduce((accum, { prop1, ...rest }) => {
  const prop1s = prop1.trim().split(' , ');
  prop1s.forEach(prop1 => accum.push({
    prop1,
    ...rest
  }));
  return accum;
}, []);
console.log(ouput);
```

Answer (score 1):

use `reduce` and `split` and `forEach`

```js
let data = [
  {
    prop1: ' text1 , text2 , text3 ',
    prop2: 'stuff1',
    prop3: 'stuff1',
    prop4: 'stuff1',
    prop5: 'https://www.stuff1.com'
  },

  {
    prop1: ' text1 , text2 , text3 ',
    prop2: 'stuff2',
    prop3: 'stuff2',
    prop4: 'stuff2',
    prop5: 'https://www.awefewfew.com'
  }
]
let res = data.reduce((re, obj) => {
  obj.prop1.split(',').forEach(val => {
    re.push(Object.assign({}, obj, { prop1: val.trim() }))
  })
  return re
}, [])
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```js
var jsonObj = [{ 
    prop1: ' text1 , text2 , text3 ',
    prop2: 'stuff1',
    prop3: 'stuff1',
    prop4: 'stuff1',
    prop5: 'https://www.stuff1.com' },
  { 
    prop1: ' text1 , text2 , text3 ',
    prop2: 'stuff2',
    prop3: 'stuff2',
    prop4: 'stuff2',
    prop5: 'https://www.awefewfew.com' }];
    
 var newArr = [];   
 
 for (var i in jsonObj) {
   var splitString = jsonObj[i].prop1.split(',');
   
   splitString.map(item => {
     newArr.push({
       "prop1": item,
       "prop2": jsonObj[i].prop2,
       "prop3": jsonObj[i].prop3,
       "prop4": jsonObj[i].prop4,
       "prop5": jsonObj[i].prop5
     });
   });
 }
 
 console.log(newArr);
```